# Setting spring.jpa.open-in-view=false makes API responses inconsistent, giving 500 error to client

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Since I started working on a spring-boot application, I use to see the following warning during service startup

> 2022-09-20 17:59:49.061  WARN 10776 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

To address this, I recently added the `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in application.properties file to disable this warning and it worked.

However, after doing so, some of the endpoints became inconsistent in sending the response! For instance:
User-1 requesting an endpoint gets `HTTP/1.1 200` response w/ JSON body
User-2 requesting the same endpoint gets `HTTP/1.1 500` response w/o any body
Ideally, both the requests should fetch a JSON response body having list of Objects (different objects based on user)

In chrome's network tab, I see the following response for User-2

```
HTTP/1.1 500
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 820
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2022 12:43:55 GMT
Connection: close
```

There are no warnings, errors, exceptions of any sorts logged in the server log. From the start of the function execution till the returning of response, all the logs seen are expected ones.

The same User-2 making the same request when `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` will fetch the following response (and 5 Objects in the list).

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2022 12:52:04 GMT
```

Is there any related configuration that needs to be done along with `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` setting? 
Also, should I really need to worry on changing the default value? How will this setting impact the application?

- My environment info:

```
Java: 1.8
MySQL: 5.7
Spring-Boot: 2.1.2.RELEASE
Spring Tool Suite: 3.9.9.RELEASE
```

- All the queries are in @Query annotation in extended JpaRepository interfaces.
- application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web = INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate = INFO
logging.level.my.packages = TRACE

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
```

I'm trying to understand the reason behind this unexpected behavior. Any info could be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have a LazyInitializationException. There MUST be an entry in the log!

Comment: Even I thought so after checking some google answers. But there are no exceptions or errors logged. (the default application logging is set to INFO)

Comment: Sorry to say but that's not possible. Did you configure some other log levels?

Comment: No. Other than these 3 log levels, root level is set to INFO.

Comment: try to run the app on the command line: mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: Thank you @SimonMartinelli. It was indeed a LazyInitializationException! I had to set log level of org.hibernate to TRACE to get `2022-09-20 23:17:26.994 TRACE 2280 --- [io-60001-exec-5] o.hibernate.LazyInitializationException  : could not initialize proxy [myClass#id] - no Session` logged.. Wondering why this exception is not seen in regular logging condition when its causing 500 error!

Comment: That's a very good question. But to answer that I would need to see your code